# Count the number of votes per post

Tags: mysql, sql, count

We're currently stuck trying to make a simple (?) SQL query.

We have these two tables:

```
create table `post` (
    `id` integer primary key
)
create table `vote` (
    `id` integer primary key,
    `post_id` references `post`.`id`, // Well ok, it's a foreign key then...
    `value` int // 1 for a positive vote, or zero for a negative one
)
```

We're trying to build a select that would, for each post, return the number of positive and negative votes: `SELECT post.id, <positive count>, <negative count> ...`

While this is not hard to do with sub-selects, the challenge begins when we try to do this without sub-selects, but with `join`. We're using `left outer join`, and the problems arise when a post has only positive or negative votes.

While I understand the problem, I can't figure out how to do that only with `join`, yet I'm confident it can be done without sub-selects. How would you do that ?

(Well, I did not include my current query, so that it won't guide you to the wrong direction...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Previous answer was rubbish, I forgot to `GROUP`. Here's an alternative that uses `CASE`, I THINK it handles the `NULL` case (since the `WHEN` clause will be `NULL`) but you may need to use `COALESCE` after all...:

```
SELECT post.id, SUM(CASE WHEN a.vote > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) up, SUM(CASE WHEN a.vote < 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) down FROM post LEFT JOIN vote a ON (a.post_id = post.id) GROUP BY post.id
```

---

Previous (incorrect) answer:

> It sounds like you need to use `COALESCE` to force a `NULL` to zero - the following might work but is untested:
>
> ```
> SELECT post.id, SUM(COALESCE(a.vote,0)), SUM(COALESCE(b.vote,0)) FROM post LEFT JOIN vote a ON (a.post_id = post.id AND value > 0) LEFT JOIN vote b ON (b.post_id = post.id AND value < 0)
> ```

Comment: Oh, I didn't know we could make "complex" join criterias... I always used simple "xx.yy_id = yy.id". Well this was the missing part, and I missed it for long ! Thank you very much (from us two ;) )